# How time.sleep changes result of this program that uses channels

Tags: go

I am new in Go and doing some practices with the book ["The little Go  book"](https://www.openmymind.net/The-Little-Go-Book/) from chapter Concurrency. I can't figure out what happens by removing `time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 50)`that changes the output to only printing results for "worker 4".

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        worker := &Worker{id: i}
        go worker.process(c)

    }
    for {
        c <- rand.Int()
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 50) // ???
    }
}

type Worker struct {
    id int
}

func (w *Worker) process(c chan int) {
    for {
        data := <-c
        fmt.Printf("worker %d got %d\n", w.id, data)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an implementation detail.  There's nothing in the program that ensures that more than one worker receives a value.

Comment: I think this talk should shed some light on what happens here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBZlN0izeiY. Interesting things happen on a blocked channel: data may flow directly from senders to receivers, bypassing the channel :)

Comment: Which Go compiler are you trying this on?

Comment: You can compile the program with/without (time.Sleep) statement in [link1](https://play.golang.org/p/WXgt-CsgZCP) and [link2](https://play.golang.org/p/GZHSSge-dND)

Comment: a) What version of Go are you using? Older versions defaulted to running single threaded. b) How many cores does your CPU have?  Basically my guess is your Go application is running on a single core and worker 4 is just happening to be ready each time you're pushing a value into the channel.

Comment: Also, try buffering the channel and see if you get the same result, e.g. c := make(chan int, 10)

Comment: @donatJ The buffering doesn't change the result. I've tried that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev everything about the statement "Interesting things happen on a blocked channel: data may flow directly from senders to receivers, bypassing the channel" is false. Data does not flow with a blocked channel, by definition, and channel communications cannot bypass the channel, by definition. *Un*blocked, *buffered* channels with an *empty* buffer can bypass the *buffer*, which is completely different (and a largely irrelevant behind-the-scenes optimization detail).

Comment: @Adrian: it is quiite possible I didn't understand that talk in enough detail :) What is your take on what's happening here?

Comment: My take is "concurrent operations are non-deterministic", i.e., *any* expectation of which worker(s) would receive which value(s) is mistaken.

Comment: @Adrian: ah, but here worker 4 gets _all_ values. Definitely something deterministic going on. Implementation detail or not, I'd like to find out.

Comment: No, it definitely does not mean something deterministic is going on. It only appears deterministic in playground because playground caches results and returns the same result for the same code instead of running it again. Running it locally reveals it to be unpredictable.